# How to print thing in for loop Console.WrileLine() in aspx

Tags: c#

This is my code i want to print these array in for loop on aspx page

```
                  for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (noteCounter[i] != 0)
                        {
                              Console.WriteLine(notes[i].Col2 + " : "
                                + noteCounter[i]);

                        }

                    }
```

It was working fine in Console Application i just changed it to the Web application Web form and now i want to print it on screen just without html and css any

Comment: `Response.Write($"{notes[i].Col2 } : {noteCounter[i]});`

Comment: a better solution is to unit testing your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Solution:

You can use `Log.Write()` instead of `Console.Write()` then check your logs on the **Output** window; Of course, you should run your app in debugging mode.

first import `System.Diagnostics`

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// skip
for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
{
         if (noteCounter[i] != 0)
         {
               Debug.WriteLine(notes[i].Col2 + " : "
                                + noteCounter[i]);

         }

}
```

### [image: Log]
Second Solution

You can log everything and save it on a separate file, then check it whenever you want to... Don't need to import anything, just write this method:

```
public void Logger(string lines)
{
  //Write the string to a file.append mode is enabled so that the log
  //lines get appended to  test.txt than wiping content and writing the log

  using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\path\\to\\log\\file.txt", true))
  {
    file.WriteLine(lines);
  }
}
```

### Third Solution

**Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core**
NET Core supports a logging API that works with a variety of built-in and third-party logging providers. This article shows how to use the logging API with built-in providers.

Most of the code examples shown in this article are from ASP.NET Core apps. The logging-specific parts of these code snippets apply to any .NET Core app that uses the Generic Host. The ASP.NET Core web app templates use the Generic Host.
[Read the full article at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

change Console.WriteLine to document.write

Comment: Ramesh Chopra can you please show me the full code i am new to C# Please